# why react three fiber doesn't render points but can draw mesh?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am having trouble rendering points using `DrawSelectedPoints` function and r3f. When I replace the points with sphere geometry, everything is rendered properly. If it helps, below is the code for `DrawSelectedPoints`.

```js
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import ClickedPointsObjectScene3D from '../../DataCore/ClickedPointsObjectScene3D';
import * as THREE from 'three'


const DrawSelectedPoints = (props) => {
    if (!(props.object instanceof ClickedPointsObjectScene3D)) {
        console.error("DrawSelectedPoints: props.object is not a ClickedPointsObjectScene3D")
        return null;
    }

    let pointsObject = props.object;
    let count = pointsObject.points.length;
    let points = pointsObject.points;
    let point_size = pointsObject.point_size;
    let point_color = pointsObject.point_color;

    let positions = new Float32Array(count * 3);  // [N, 3] -> [N*3]
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        positions[3 * i] = points[i][0];
        positions[3 * i + 1] = points[i][1];
        positions[3 * i + 2] = points[i][2];
    }

    let colors = new Float32Array(count * 3);
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        colors[3 * i] = 1;
        colors[3 * i + 1] = 0;
        colors[3 * i + 2] = 0;
    }

    // The mesh can be rendered properly
    // return (
    //     <group position={[0, 0, 0]}>
    //         {points.map((point, index) => {
    //             return (
    //                 <mesh key={index} position={point}>
    //                     <sphereBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[point_size, 16, 16]} />
    //                     <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color={point_color} />
    //                 </mesh>
    //             )
    //         })}
    //     </group>
    // )

    // points are not rendered...
    return (
        <points>
            <bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
                <bufferAttribute
                    attach="attributes-position"
                    array={positions}
                    count = {count}
                    itemSize={3}
                />
            </bufferGeometry>
            <pointsMaterial attach="material" color={point_color} size={point_size} sizeAttenuation={true} />
        </points>);
}

export default DrawSelectedPoints;
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/points-ldpyw8?file=/src/index.js, points component works in react three fiber.